# How can I filter a list so a collection it contains has at least one element?

Tags: c#

I have the following:

```
var t = _qRepository.GetAll();
```

This returns a list of `IList<Q>`

```
public class Q
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<A> As { get; set; }
}
```

How can I filter my list t so that `As` has at least one item in the collection? The problem for me is that `As` is virtual so 
how do I make it get the `As` collection? Note that I don't have lazy loading enabled.

Answer (score 2):

```
var t = _qRepository.GetAll().Where(q => q.As.Any());
```